# Filling in 2D array diagonally

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

I need to fill in this 2D array diagonally and I am not sure how it should look like this.

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DbRa3.jpg)

Here is what I have

```
for(int i=0; i < matrix.length; i++ )  
    matrix[i][i] = i;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you would like the matrix to be filled the way it is on the picture, do a little manipulation with indexes ([demo](http://ideone.com/AWVfBz)):

```
int last = matrix.length-1;
for(int i=0; i < matrix.length; i++ )  
      matrix[i][last-i] = last-i;
```

Producing the same output can be achieved by printing the lines of the matrix starting from the last one going backward.

Answer (score 0):

This will work only if it is a square 2 dimensional array,
and will fill one of the diagonals only (upper left to lower right).

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit messy, but what you need is that:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
  int n = 5; // dimension of the array
  int[][] matrix = new int[n][n];
  int count = matrix[0].length - 1;
  int xcurr = 0;
  int ycurr = count;

  for(int x=0; x < matrix[0].length; x++) {
      for (int y=0; y < matrix[0].length; y++) {
          if (x == xcurr && y == ycurr) {
              matrix[x][y] = count;
              ycurr --;
              xcurr ++;
              count --;
          } else {
              matrix[x][y] = 0;
          }
      }
  }

  for(int i=0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
      System.err.println(Arrays.toString(matrix[i]));
  }
}
```

[DEMO HERE](http://ideone.com/Za4OGZ)

Answer (score 0):

It could be done in a number of ways, here's one:

```
// Initializing the array
    int[] array =
            {
                    0, 0, 0, 0, 4,
                    0, 0, 0, 3, 0,
                    0, 0, 2, 0, 0,
                    0, 1, 0, 0, 0,
                    0, 0, 0, 0, 0
            };

    // Iteration of the loop for printing
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (i % 5 != 0) // while is not divisible with 5
        {
            System.out.print(array[i]);
            System.out.print(" "); // Spaces between numbers
        } else // Makes new line for every fifth iteration
        {
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
```

I hope it makes sense from the comments.

Comment: woops. Probably misunderstood the question. Thought you just wanted to print an array as show in the picture.